# C# - Format float WITHOUT tail zeros

Tags: c#, formatting

Is that possible in C# to format

`4.52` float number to `4.52` string

and

`4.520` float number to `4.52` string, i.e. omitting tail zeros?

**EDIT: I think I've not accented the real problem.
I need ONE pattern that conforms BOTH of the above examples!**

Comment: check this out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx

Comment: Do you need to omit only after the second decimal point?

Comment: This isn't a real question is it?  4.52 and 4.520 are both idential.  Also this is describing the default behaviour of float.ToString().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you want to omit *any* trailing 0's from your value, this should give you what you want:

```
ToString("0.####")
```

Otherwise you could do:

```
ToString("0.00##")
```

Answer (score 4):

See [this](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/) website for examples.

i.e

```
String.Format("{0:0.00}", 4.520);      // "4.52"
```

Comment: I imagine the OP wanted a solution for any float.  Not just a float with two decimal places.

Comment: What do you mean? he can change the format as he would like, he asked for 2 digits after the dot - thats what the example above does. it can be changed easily!

Comment: Well.. you seam to be assuming he knows at compile time what the number is.  But if he knew that then he would get better performance from `"4.52"`.

Comment: Heh, so how about 
double dNum = ... (ANYTHING?);
String.Format("{0:0.00}", dNum); 

Then again, maybe i'm getting you wrong :-)

Comment: He wants to remove trailing zeros, not force all floats to have two decimal places.

Comment: @Shai Thanks for your answer but Buh Buh here right! He wrote exactly what I needed.

Comment: @Buh Buh Thanks pal! I've choose the most appropriate answer for me. See if u r interested

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you don't need a pattern. .NET always omits the tail zeros of float numbers, unless specified to do not.

So `Console.WriteLine(4.520)` would output `4.52`, as would `Console.WriteLine(4.52)` or `Console.WriteLine(4.520000000000)`, as `Console.WriteLine(4.5)` would output `4.5`.

In the example above, the `System.Console.WriteLine` method will internally call `ToString()` (with no patterns) on your float number.

Also, if you're looking for something more specific, you can take a look at

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.71).aspx

for some more number format strings.

Comment: Just an FYI - this uses the "G" format specifier implicitly so you would just need to make sure that using `ToString` won't round up or format it differently based on the precision etc - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#GFormatString

Comment: Yes, according to the link above, the limit of digits turned into a string by the "G" format specifier is 7 for floats, 15 for doubles and 29 for decimals.

Comment: Thanks @Raphael but I want little different behavior

Answer (score 1):

All of these result in "4.52":

```
string formatted = 4.52.ToString();
string formatted = 4.520.ToString();
```

Because that was too easy I wonder if maybe your float is really a string:

```
string formatted = "4.52".Trim('0');
string formatted = "4.520".Trim('0');
```

Comment: I want to do it for ALL float numbers, i.e. I have variable float d = ...; and it should be written with N-digits after point BUT that digits CAN NOT be tail zeros

Comment: N-digits?  Please define N.  Do you mean you want a method like this: `string Format(float d, int nDecimalPlaces);`  Or is N always two?

Comment: Also, `ALL float numbers` have `.ToString()`